# Ibus m17n languages not seen in 14.04 gnome-classic

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-classic, ibus

Input methods of ibus-m17n can't be selected from Text Entry Settings in gnome-classic desktop environment. But it can be selected when logged in to Unity. Is there a problem between gnome-classic and ibus in 14.04.?

Is there a way to fix it or this is a bug in gnome-classic in 14.04.?

Comment: Same problem. And we're not alone according to many posts.